# Openstack compute node not shown as hypervisor

Tags: java, openstack

I recently set up an devstack environment and added another compute node. The compute node is not shown as an hypervisor as seen here:

This is the output of `openstack hypervisor list`

> +----+---------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------+
>   | ID | Hypervisor Hostname | Hypervisor Type | Host IP      | State |
>   +----+---------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------+
>   |  1 | openstack-1         | QEMU            |0.0.0.0       | up    |
>   +----+---------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------+

The compute node is correctly shown in horizon under the compute node section. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Which credentials are you using in the CLI? If you are using the `demo` user, then the output makes sense (since listing compute nodes is an admin-only operation). Using the `admin` credentials should show the compute node in the CLI output.

Answer (score 0):

1st Try this command

```
# su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 discover_hosts --verbose" nova
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, I'm installing a single compute node openstack Train and my hypervisor is not shown, I tried the command and problem resolved.